# Resize an inset UITextView when device rotates

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitextview, xcode9

I have a UIView called detailView with two child views, a UITextView called detailTextView and a UIImageView called detailImageView, that are siblings of one another.  The detailView is contained within the default detail UIView from a split view.  I am using autoresizing to set all this up in my main storyboard.  Visually, the hierarchy is as follows:

```
Top Layout Guide
Bottom Layout Guide
View
- Detail View
- - Detail Text View
- - Detail Image View
Navigation Item
```

The detailTextView is inset 10% from each side, has a blurred edge, and cross-dissolves on top of the image when the view appears, as follows:

```
/**
 - reference:
 Joy, V. (2016, December 15). Swift 3: How to create blurred side edges/
 corners of a UIImageView?. Message posted to
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/41158594/6084947
 */
internal override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    print("detailViewDidAppear")

    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    // Resize the text view.
    let inset = detailView.bounds.width * 0.2
    detailTextView.frame = CGRect(
        x: inset / 2,
        y: inset / 2,
        width: detailView.bounds.width - inset,
        height: detailView.bounds.height - inset
    )

    // Set up text view attributes.
    detailTextView.allowsEditingTextAttributes = true

    let xInset = detailTextView.bounds.width * 0.05
    let yInset = detailTextView.bounds.height * 0.05
    detailTextView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(
        yInset,
        xInset,
        yInset,
        xInset
    )

    // Blur edges of text view (see Joy, 2016).
    let maskLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    maskLayer.frame = detailTextView.bounds
    maskLayer.shadowRadius = 5
    maskLayer.shadowPath = CGPath(
        roundedRect: detailTextView.bounds.insetBy(dx: 5, dy: 5),
        cornerWidth: 10,
        cornerHeight: 10,
        transform: nil
    )
    maskLayer.shadowOpacity = 1
    maskLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
    maskLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    detailTextView.layer.mask = maskLayer

    // Fade in text view.
    UIView.transition(
        with: detailView,
        duration: 3,
        options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
        animations:
        { self.detailView.bringSubview(toFront: self.detailTextView) },
        completion: nil
    )
}
```

The problem is that the inset detailTextView does not resize properly when the screen rotates.  When loading the detail view from landscape mode, it does not fill up the super view when rotating to portrait mode on the iPad simulator.

I've tried the following:

```
internal override func viewWillTransition(
    to size: CGSize,
    with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)
{
    print("viewWillTransition")

    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: nil) {
        [unowned self] _ in

        // Resize text view.
        let inset = size.width * 0.2
        self.detailTextView.frame = CGRect(
            x: inset / 2,
            y: inset / 2,
            width: size.width - inset,
            height: size.height - inset
        )
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't help the landscape-to-portrait transition and leaves me with a bunch of bounds to adjust.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Size classes for iPads are the same unless in some type of split screen mode. Do not use `size`. Instead - you *do* have the correct override - use the main view's `bounds`. (In other words, you have things correct IMO.)

Comment: Thanks, but replacing `size` with `self.view.bounds` didn't help.  When rotating landscape-to-portrait, the text view still does not enlarge to fill up the bottom half of the screen.

Comment: BTW, there is both master and detail of the split view visible when in landscape mode on the iPad.

Comment: I think the answer is at 13:45 of [Stanford - Developing iOS 9 Apps with Swift - 4. Views](https://youtu.be/jcxp1bbXbL4?t=13m45s).  I'll answer my own question soon if that is indeed the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not the resizing of my UITextView or its inset, which I discovered, with a few print statements, was working as-expected and automatically.  Rather, the problem was that the mask layer that I created for blurring edges was not resizing.  The following (which uses insetBy(dx:dy:) to change the bounds of the UITextView instead of its frame) is my corrected code:

```
/**
 - reference:
 Joy, V. (2016, December 15). Swift 3: How to create blurred side edges/
 corners of a UIImageView?. Message posted to
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/41158594/6084947
 */
internal override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    print("detailViewDidAppear")

    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    // Resize the text view.
    let textViewInset = detailView.bounds.width * 0.1
    detailTextView.bounds = detailView.bounds.insetBy(
        dx: textViewInset,
        dy: textViewInset
    )

    // Set up text view attributes.
    detailTextView.allowsEditingTextAttributes = true

    let textContainerInset = detailTextView.bounds.width * 0.05
    detailTextView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(
        textContainerInset,
        textContainerInset,
        textContainerInset,
        textContainerInset
    )

    // Blur edges of text view (see Joy, 2016).
    let maskLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    maskLayer.frame = detailTextView.bounds
    maskLayer.shadowRadius = 5
    maskLayer.shadowPath = CGPath(
        roundedRect: detailTextView.bounds.insetBy(dx: 5, dy: 5),
        cornerWidth: 10,
        cornerHeight: 10,
        transform: nil
    )
    maskLayer.shadowOpacity = 1
    maskLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
    maskLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    detailTextView.layer.mask = maskLayer

    // Fade in text view.
    UIView.transition(
        with: detailView,
        duration: 3,
        options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
        animations:
        { self.detailView.bringSubview(toFront: self.detailTextView) },
        completion: nil
    )
}

/**
 - reference:
 Joy, V. (2016, December 15). Swift 3: How to create blurred side edges/
 corners of a UIImageView?. Message posted to
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/41158594/6084947
 */
internal override func viewWillTransition(
    to size: CGSize,
    with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)
{
    print("viewWillTransition")

    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: nil) {
        [unowned self] _ in

        // Blur edges of text view (see Joy, 2016).
        let maskLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        maskLayer.frame = self.detailTextView.bounds
        maskLayer.shadowRadius = 5
        maskLayer.shadowPath = CGPath(
            roundedRect: self.detailTextView.bounds.insetBy(dx: 5, dy: 5),
            cornerWidth: 10,
            cornerHeight: 10,
            transform: nil
        )
        maskLayer.shadowOpacity = 1
        maskLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
        maskLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        self.detailTextView.layer.mask = maskLayer
    }
}
```